# Rails 5 deprecation warning and adding code to initializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To which initializer file should I add the desired line of code?
I'm getting the following deprecation warning.

DEPRECATION WARNING: Time columns will become time zone aware in Rails 5.1. This still causes `String`s to be parsed as if they were in `Time.zone`,
and `Time`s to be converted to `Time.zone`.

To keep the old behavior, you must add the following to your initializer:

```
config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime]
```

To silence this deprecation warning, add the following:

```
config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime, :time]
```

I'm a rails newbie, I just want to follow best practice. Thanks!

Comment: if you go to either `config/environments/development.rb` or `config/application.rb`, you'll find that you have access to the `config` object, you can add that line to any of those files. If you want it to work for all your environments, put it in `application.rb`.

Comment: Perfect! I put the code inside application.rb

Comment: the error message says `To keep the old behavior, you must add the following to your INITIALIZER`. I tried adding it to an initializer `/config/initializers/time_zone_aware_types.rb` by adding following content `Rails.application.config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime, :time]` to it but strangely it didn't worked. Ultimately I ended up adding the same content to `/config/application.rb` and it worked. Either the warning message should be fixed or it should clearly convey the file name in which this should go

Answer (score 9):

add to `config/application.rb` inside `class Application < Rails::Application` this line:

```
config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime, :time]
```

Answer (score 3):

create file **/config/initializers/time_zone_aware_types.rb**
then add next line to the file
`Rails.application.config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime, :time]`